# Program type out of range connecting to MS SQL

Tags: c++, sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc

ALL,

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT cast(su.name AS varchar(128)) FROM sysobjects so, sysusers su, sys.tables t, sys.schemas s WHERE so.uid = su.uid AND t.object_id = so.id AND t.schema_id = s.schema_id AND s.name = ? AND so.name = ?;
```

against SQL Server 10.0 (as returned from `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')`) and am receiving the aforementioned error.

The only google result for this error and MS SQL Server is [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/238774/prb-odbc-driver-manager-error-program-type-out-of-range), but doing what is recommended as a 2nd solution didn't work.

Code I use is as follows:

```
SQLSMALLINT nameBufLength, dataTypePtr, decimalDigitsPtr, isNullable;
SQLULEN columnSizePtr;
SQLLEN cbTableOwner;
retcode = SQLDescribeCol( stmt, 1, NULL, 0, &nameBufLength, &dataTypePtr, &columnSizePtr, &decimalDigitsPtr, &isNullable );
if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
{
    owner = new SQLWCHAR[columnSizePtr + 1];
    retcode = SQLBindCol( stmt, 1, dataTypePtr, &owner, columnSizePtr, &cbTableOwner );
    if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
    {
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why am I getting the error? It's not even mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindcol-function).

TIA!

---

EDIT:

I am using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 ODBC driver version 2011.110.2100.60 from 11 Feb 2012. I also have SQL Server Native Client 10.0 installed. The driver I use should be backward compatible. But I will try with 10.0 just in case tomorrow.

---

EDIT2:

Trying to use older driver also didn't work. I guess I will try to workaround the error.

Comment: I don't have any experience with ODBC but based on the linked article and your query I would recommend trying the following: `.... AND CAST( s.name AS VARCHAR( 256 )) = ? AND CAST( so.name AS VARCHAR( 256 )) = ?` just to see if it will work. You can also try using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @Alex, Nope, still the same error. The query works just fine in the SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: @Alex, trying the older driver didn't work as well. I will try to implement a workaround.

Comment: Do you know which parameter or return column this error applies to? Can you try running this query without input parameters and hard code "some string" as the return data e.g. `SELECT "some string" as name FROM sysobjects so, sysusers su, sys.tables t, sys.schemas s WHERE so.uid = su.uid AND t.object_id = so.id AND t.schema_id = s.schema_id `. If it works, start adding parameters one by one and then add back the column to the `select`

Comment: @Alex, the failure occurs at `SQLBindCol()` call. Nothing to do with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In `SQLBindCol()`, set the `dataTypePtr` to `SQL_WCHAR` instead of `SQL_WVARCHAR` for unicode and to `SQL_CHAR` instead of `SQL_VARCHAR` for ascii.